# Include missing dates as "0" in SELECT ... A,count(A) group BY (Google Sheets, or SQL)

Tags: sql, group-by, google-sheets

I am creating a histogram of dates using SQL and I want to have "0" values for the missing dates. The specific SQL system I'm using is Google Sheets. Here is my example:

[image]

What I really want is for it to look like this:
[image]

Is there any way to do this?

The query that I'm using is `SELECT a,COUNT(a) GROUP BY a ORDER BY a`.

Is there a way to do what I want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a column of the dates you want. For instance, you can put in the first date, the right below it have a formula that adds one day, and copy the formula down.

Then, use [`COUNTIF`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093480) or a similar function to get the counts you want, e.g.:

```
=COUNTIF($A$1:$A:$5,"=" & C2)
```

[image: 2]